# ConvertFrom-StringData clear hash-table

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am attempting to parse multiple mails in a specific mail folder, to eventually create a csv file with the information.

If I run the script on one user, the output I get is perfect;

```
Name                           Value                                                          
----                           -----                                                          
Kontor.                        HR                      
Prøvetid                       Ja                                                            
Blomster på dagen              Nej                                                            
Telefonnr.                     85789845                                                      
Adresse                        Hovedgade 13                                                  
Ansættes i stedet for          Ninette Kock                                    
Navn                           Marianne Pedersen                                                
Etage                          1. sal                                                        
Fri telefon                    Ja                                                            
Benyttet navn                  Marianne Pedersen                                                
Medarbejdertype                Fastansat                                                      
Overtagelse af mobilnr.        Ja                                                            
Placering                      Sydøst                                                        
Ansættelsesdato                01-01-2020                                                    
Stilling                       Fuldmægtig                                                    
Lokalnr.                       +45 3370 0000                                                
Besked til IT-centret                                                                        
Antal timer                    37                                                            
Journalistpraktikant           Nej                                                            
Tidl. ansat                    Nej                                                            
Initialer                      MAPE                                                          
Blomster anden dag             02-01-2020                                                    
Postnr/By                      2630 Taastrup                                              
Cpr. nr.                       XXXX
```

The problem is when I try to parse a second mail, the first mail will still get parsed correctly, but the second one will throw an error;

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item 'Medarbejdertype' in line 'Medarbejdertype=Fastansat' is 
already defined.
```

If I try to parse the second mail as the first mail, it will parse perfectly.
Problem happens when I try to parse more then one.

I have tried to clear the hash-table like so;

```
$data.clear()
clear-variable -name data
$data = @{}
```

But it somehow seems that the hash-table is not emptied?
The code I am using:

```
Clear-Host
$navne = "MAJE", "ASHO"

# create an instance of Outlook 
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$nameSpace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMlFile"

# Opens and save all mails in Nye Til Oprettelse in $mails.
$mails = $nameSpace.Folders.Item('hotline').Folders.Item('Indbakke').Folders.Item('@HOVSA''er').Folders.Item('@01Nye til oprettelse').Items | Select-Object -Property subject, htmlbody

# Loop over $mails, check if $navn = subject
foreach ($navn in $navne) {
    foreach ($mail in $mails) {
        if($mail | Where-Object {$_.subject -match "$Navn"}) {
            #$mail.HTMLBody
            # write data to $html, then find all <table> tags and parse that text.
            $html.IHTMLDOCUMENT2_write($mail.HTMLBody)
            $data = $html.all.tags("table") | % innertext 
            $data = $data -split '\r?\n' -match '^[^:]+:[^:]+$' -replace ':\s*', '=' -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
            $navn
            $data
            $data = @[]
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending each email to the `$html` document using `$html.IHTMLDOCUMENT2_write($mail.HTMLBody)`, but you only initialise it once at the top of your script, so each time your `foreach ($mail in $mails)` loops you add **another** email to the document.

That means the second time the loop iterates there are *two* emails in the `$html` document and you're getting an error about duplicate data items as a result.

Try moving `$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMlFile"` *inside* your `foreach` loop so it reads:

```
foreach ($mail in $mails) {
    ...
    $html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMlFile"
    $html.IHTMLDOCUMENT2_write($mail.HTMLBody)
    ...
}
```

P.S.: You might also want to look at using a non-COM library like the [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to do your html processing - it'll potentially be a bit faster and more reliable (and portable) in an automation script than COM is.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks for pointing out the mistake :) I will take a look into HTML Agility Pack.